# What does the `>` operator do in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```py
export_file_name = 'output.csv'
export_df = pd.read_csv(export_file_name)
companies = export_df[export_df['title'] > ''].company_name.to_list()
```

I was wondering what the `>` operator does in this case?

Comment: Type `export_df['title'] > ''` and see the output (True and False)

Comment: So I get a bunch of True values but im still not quite sure ..

Comment: [Lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) may be of help, basically alphabetic order extended to all the characters

Comment: Are you saying that it sorts the entries of the dataframe?

Comment: No, I'm saying there is a natural meaning for greater-than applied to text

Comment: You get a True value for the rows that will be picked up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export_df` is a data frame, and `export_df['title']` returns a series of titles from that file. In Pandas, many operators are overloaded for series types, so, for example when dealing with series:

```
export_df['title'] > ''
```

is equivalent to:

```
export_df['title'].gt('')
```

That returns a series of boolean values in the same order: each non-empty title will have `True` on the corresponding position, and each empty will have `False`.

Consequently, when you provide that sequence of boolean values as an index to the original data frame, it will return a new data frame that includes only the rows with `True` on the corresponding positions, i.e. those with non-empty titles.

This is an idiomatic way to [filter data frame rows](https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/02/how-to-subset-pandas-dataframe-based-on-values-of-a-column/) in Pandas.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation over my original answer, i failed to see the reference to Pandas and was referring to regular Lists